# Locating picture to the left, but the text centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I want to have my the `picture.png` to be exactly on the very left of the title "ribbon", and the text to be centred about the ribbon (regardless of the presence of the picture). I've been struggling with CSS and flex boxes for a lot of time trying to achieve just this effect. Here I'm using some bootstrap classes, but `.heading` is my class.

That being said, is it actually possible to do all this alignment without using flexbox, but something more natural and simple? Such as maybe something from CSS1, without all those flex boxes?

```css
.heading {
  background-color: rgba(15, 156, 199, 0.829);
  height: 5%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* not helpful of course */
}


/* Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I made this by artificially adding the following CSS code: */

.name {
  margin-right: 31%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-sm">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="heading">
      <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="picture.png" alt="...">
      <div class="name">
        <h4>Web server monitoring and maintenance.</h4>
        <div>Monitoring and upgrades.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course I want this to be naturally centred, not artificially.

[image]

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use `flex` or `grid`?

Comment: It seems rather odd that you're looking to avoid `flex` when Bootstrap itself relies on it.

Comment: @cSharp I want to make code as simple as possible.

Comment: Simpler code is a noble goal, but [CSS1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/) is 26 years old (as of 2022) and doesn't contain any layout features but simple styling and selectors. Believe it or not, `flex` or `grid` might be the _simplest_ solutions there are for vertical and horizontal centering with fine controls. If already using Bootstrap, there might be utilizing its utility classes too—but I wouldn't know as I haven't touched Bootstrap in several years.

Comment: @BumhanYu How did people do a similar thing (that which my question is about) with CSS1 or without CSS at all?

Comment: **Short answer:** they didn't do it at all in 1990s, and then started using `table` or `frameset` markups (note how these are `html` tags and not `css`). **Longer answer:** HTML layouts used to be very basic top-down content flow, and people didn't expect sophisticated structure. It was more or less Word doc-like pages. Thus the nomenclature "web _page_". When such centering was needed as what you're describing, people would've had to rely on `table` _HTML_ markup, not proper _CSS_ styling.

Comment: Technically, you _can_ still use `table` to achieve what you outlined above. But since it isn't truly _tabular data_ you're presenting (e.g. unlike a shopping cart summary, financial report, etc), using a `table` wouldn't be less semantic and thus not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR. Make your `.name` also a `flex` container.

Please see the code snippet below. I didn't edit the HTML except the placeholder image. The main CSS change is in `.name` class to make it `flex` container and have its content vertically centered. Also, its parent `.heading` styles are a little adjusted to make it work properly.

```css
.heading {
  background-color: rgba(15, 156, 199, 0.829);
  height: 5%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h4, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-sm">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="heading">
      <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="...">
      <div class="name">
        <h4>Web server monitoring and maintenance.</h4>
        <div>Monitoring and upgrades.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap relies on Flexbox for the alignment and layouts. So it will be odd to avoid using it.

Here is a code snippet that will help you achieve what you want to do.

Helpful links:

Bootstrap Flexbox: [Flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/)

CSS Flexbox: [MDN flexbox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.heading {
    background-color: rgba(15, 156, 199, 0.829);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-sm">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="heading d-flex text-center">
      <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="picture.png" alt="...">
      <div class="name flex-grow-1">
        <h4>Web server monitoring and maintenance.</h4>
        <p>Monitoring and upgrades.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Bootstrap is all about pre-made components and utility classes so try to avoid writing custom CSS as much as possible. Another downside of this is that you're repeating yourself and making Bootstrap useless in the manner you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

using flexbox

```css
img,.image {
height:50px;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height:50px;
  
}
.text-wrapper{
   background-color: rgba(15, 156, 199, 0.829);
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container{
  padding:5px;
}
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Web server monitoring and maintenance.</h4>
      <p>Monitoring and upgrades.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```